# Android App to monitor training status of models from Google AI Platform

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, android-wear-notification, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to build an Android App using Java and Android Studio that will monitor the training status of your models on Google Cloud AI Platform and send a notification to a Wearable when the training is done.

I have been looking for APIs I can use but I am a bit confused as I see a lot of people talking about 'generated apis'. So far I think this is what I need to use but I am not sure if it will work with Android.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the docs, seems that there is no method that could monitor your progress in the training.

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict

Generated API Clients (GAPICs) are the Google’s newest and most powerful APIs are built with gRPC, an open-source RPC framework that grew from technologies developed at Google. https://googleapis.github.io/#generated-api-clients-gapics

These are like client libraries that uses the model of RPC.

Maybe you can try to attach a notification with some other GCP product like Pub/Sub or Cloud Functions but I am not really sure that this could works for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: Actually, I think this is what I am looking for but, I am unsure of some things https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs

Comment: 1. Do I need authentication to make a google cloud REST api call? and 2. The request needs to be a Scope? Are there any more detailed tutorials out there?